# Mandar mas de una variable php por medio de un evento onclick y recibirlo con javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

Buenas tardes acudo a ustedes nuevamente, esta vez tengo una gran duda que no me deja avanzar en mi proyecto, y es que tengo un enlace el cual por medio de un evento onclick envió una variable php y la recibo en javascript hasta ahí sin ningún problema, el detalle es que tengo otras 3 variables que quiero enviar por medio de ese evento pero no se como, si me pueden apoyar por favor para enviarla y recibirla se los super agradecería.

Dejo el código.

Lo que deseo es poder enviar por esa misma variable otras variables php y recibirla en la función js para así poder enviarlas a otra pagina php donde imprimo un pdf.

```js
function ver_estudios(numero_factura){
        VentanaCentrada('ver_estudios_pacientes.php?numero_factura='+numero_factura,'Nota','','1024','768','true');
        }
```

```html
<a href="#" class='btn btn-default' title='Ver estudios del paciente' onclick="ver_estudios('<?php echo $numero_factura;?>');"><img src="img/pdf2.png" alt="guardar" width="20" height="20"> Ver estudios</a>
```

////////////  Actualización ///////////////////////////

Hola estimado Carlos gracias por tomarte tu tiempo en responderme y ayudarme y te muestro los cambios que hice como actualizacion en el mismo tema, y no se si lo estoy haciendo correctamente por que lo hice como me lo planteaste y esos valores lo mando a una pagina aparte por medio de referido.

```js
funtion ver_estudios(jsonstring){
                obj=JSON.parse(jsonstring);
                var numero_factura = jsonstring.obj1;
                var idcliente      = jsonstring.obj2;
                var fecha          = jsonstring.obj3;
                var idmedico             = jsonstring.obj4;
                VentanaCentrada('ver_estudios_pacientes.php?numero_factura='+numero_factura+'&idcliente='+cli+'&fecha='+fecha+'&idmedico='+medic,'Nota','','1024','768','true');
        }
```

```html
<a href="#" class='btn btn-default' title='Ver estudios del paciente' onclick="ver_estudios({'obj1':'<?php echo $numero_factura;?>','obj2':'<?php echo $id_cliente;?>','obj3':'<?php echo $fecha;?>','obj4':'<?php echo $id_medico;?>'});"><img src="img/pdf2.png" alt="guardar" width="20" height="20"> Ver estudios</a>
```

No se si lo estoy haciendo bien o mal :(, espero me puedas ayudar.

Comment: Buenas, ¿que hace tu función VentanaCentrada?, ¿cuales son las variable que deseas mandar?

Comment: Hola buenas tardes orlando lo que hace es que imprimo un pdf y lo que hace es que lo muestra en una ventana centrada mi estimado en vez de redirigirlo al navegador. y  envio los parametros asi: VentanaCentrada('ver_estudios_pacientes.php?numero_factura='+numero_factura+'&idcliente='+cli+'&fecha='+fecha+'&idmedico='+medic,'Nota','','1024','768','true');

Comment: puedes imprimir en <input type="hidden" id="cli" value="<?=$valorCliente;?>" y luego rescatar esos valores con javascript mediante el   `` var cli = document.getElementById('cli').value; ``  ahi ya tienes por ejemplo el valor cliente en javascript

Comment: es que lo tendria que poner en un boton y el tipo boton submit ya lo tengo agregado para otra funcion aparte en el cual envio a otra pagina otros valores con input tipo hidden, y la unica manera que tengo es esta enviar por medio de un enlace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buenas tardes solo para comentar que ya pude realizar lo que me estaba dando tanta lata y lo hice de la siguiente forma, por si alguien en algún futuro le sirve de ayuda:

```js
function ver_estudios(numero_factura,fecha,id_cliente,id_medico){
                var cli = id_cliente;
                var fecha = fecha;
                var med = id_medico;
                VentanaCentrada('ver_estudios_pacientes.php?numero_factura='+numero_factura+'&idcliente='+cli+'&fecha='+fecha+'&idmedico='+med,'Nota','','1024','768','true')
            }
```

```html
<a href="#" class='btn btn-default' title='Ver estudios del paciente' onclick="ver_estudios('<?php echo $numero_factura;?>','<?php echo $fecha;?>','<?php echo $id_cliente;?>','<?php echo $id_medico;?>');"><img src="img/pdf2.png" alt="guardar" width="20" height="20"> Ver estudios</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes intentar hacer esto manejarlo como JSON:

```
onclick="ver_estudios({'obj1':'valor1','obj2':'valor2','obj3':'valor3'})"
```

y cuando revisivas los parametros

```
funtion ver_estudios(jsonstring){
objs=JSON.parse(jsonstring);
var valor1=objs.obj1;
var valor2=objs.obj2;
var valor3=objs.obj3;
}
```